# What is $(N)+ (N-1) + (N -2) + \cdots + 1$ called?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is purely for figuring the name of a mathematical concept.

For example, $N \times (N-1) \times \cdots \times  1$ is called factorial.

Question: What is $N + (N-1) + (N -2) + \cdots + 1$ called?

Comment: Is it a Sequence?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I am wondering what is the name of this thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sum of numbers from $1$ to $n$ is called a "[Triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Formula):

> The triangle numbers are given by the following explicit formulas:
> $$T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{k = 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}} = \binom{n + 1}{2},$$

So, the first triangular numbers are:

$
    T_1 = 1\\
    T_2 = 1 + 2 = 3\\
    T_3 = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6\\
    T_4 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10\\
    ...etc
$

Comment: why did n(n+1)/2 become (n+1)/2 ? Shouldn't it be (n^2 + n)/2 ?

Comment: @TSR The second part isn't $(n + 1) / 2$, it's the [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), or the [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), it is read as "$n + 1$ choose $2$" and computes the number of possible combinations of size $2$ from a set of size $n + 1$.